# Anylogic constructor PalletRack not working

Tags: anylogic

In the Anylogic 8.3 version PalletRack constructor works fine as defined:

```
PalletRack palletRack1 = new PalletRack(root, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 760.0, 90.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
        11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 2, 1000, cyan, maroon, 100 );
```

But when install the newest version of Anylogic (8.7.2) the PalletRack constructor not work the error message is:

```
Description: The constructor PalletRack(Main, ShapeDrawMode, boolean, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, PalletRackType, PalletRackDirection, double, double, double, int, int, int, Color, Color, int) is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that there is one new argument is expected in this constructor.
It is "boolean isObstacle". And its expected at 4th position.

So this code is compiled sucessfully:
PalletRack palletRack1 = new PalletRack(root, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, false, 760.0, 90.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 2, 1000, cyan, maroon, 100 );